# Reversing downvotes showing up on voting summary

Tags: support, voting, summary

When I have reversed a downvote, does this affect my voting summary of total upvotes and downvotes?

Comment: Note the vote summary numbers are cached server side so you won't see the change instantly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  It's as if the downvote was never cast in the first place.